# How to split a list of Adresse in Hex by weight in many small lists

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, knapsack-problem

I must divide a list of hexadecimal addresses into 4 parts by weighing by the difference between two successive addresses.

Example of List:

```
[0x10004158, 0x10004166, 0x100041a0, 0x100041e8, 0x100041f4, 0xb00ac668,0xb00ac672, 0xb00ac676, 0xb00ac67e, 0xb00ac682, 0xb00ac686, 0xb00c077f]
```

The weight is calculated by the difference between two successive addresses `0xb00c077f- 0x10004158 = 0xA00BC627` .

The goal is to create as few minilists as possible near `0x80000` but not to exceed this number.

In the end we will have minilists created. (The goal is to make the difference between the first and last address of the list not to be greater than 0x80000 but closer to this value.)

1. List 1 `Start Adresse`, `End Adresse`
2. List 2 `Start Adresse`, `End Adresse`
3. List 2 `Start Adresse`, `End Adresse`
4. List 4 `Start Adresse`, `End Adresse`

code:

```
import sys
import os
import time
import re
import glob
import numpy as np

class VXINI:

    def __init__(self, pfad):
        self.pfad = pfad
        print self.findA2l()
        print self.findMap()
        print ("**** VX.ini Generator V1.0****** \n " + pfad)

    def generator(self, parts):
        myList = []
        myListPoint = []
        patern= re.compile("VALUE (0x[a-f0-9]{5,8})|ECU_ADDRESS (0x[a-f0-9]{5,8})")
        for i , line in enumerate(open(self.findA2l())):
            for match in re.finditer(patern, line):
                filterString = match.group()
                filterS = filterString.replace('ECU_ADDRESS ','')
                filterFinal = filterS.replace('VALUE ','')
                #print '%s: %s' % (i+i, filterFinal)
                myList.append(filterFinal)
        myList.sort()
        print 'Number of Adresses %s:' % len(myList)
        test = np.array_split(myList,parts)
        print 'Number of Parts %s:' % len(test)
        print '================================'
        diffArr0 = hex(self.sToH(test[0][len(test[0])-1])-self.sToH(test[0][0]))
        print diffArr0
        diffArr1 = hex(self.sToH(test[1][len(test[1])-1])-self.sToH(test[1][0]))
        diffArr2 = hex(self.sToH(test[2][len(test[2])-1])-self.sToH(test[2][0]))
        diffArr3 = hex(self.sToH(test[3][len(test[3])-1])-self.sToH(test[3][0]))
        diffArr4 = hex(self.sToH(test[4][len(test[4])-1])-self.sToH(test[4][0]))
        diffArr5 = hex(self.sToH(test[5][len(test[5])-1])-self.sToH(test[5][0]))
        diffArr6 = hex(self.sToH(test[6][len(test[6])-1])-self.sToH(test[6][0]))
        diffArr7 = hex(self.sToH(test[7][len(test[7])-1])-self.sToH(test[7][0]))    
        print 'Start Adresse %s: Size:%s Size compare to 0x80000 Size: %s' % (test[0][0],diffArr0,self.checkSize(diffArr0))
        print 'Start Adresse %s: Size:%s Size compare to 0x80000 Size: %s' % (test[1][0],diffArr1,self.checkSize(diffArr1))
        print 'Start Adresse %s: Size:%s Size compare to 0x80000 Size: %s' % (test[2][0],diffArr2, self.checkSize(diffArr2))
        print 'Start Adresse %s: Size:%s Size compare to 0x80000 Size: %s' % (test[3][0],diffArr3, self.checkSize(diffArr3))
        print 'Start Adresse %s: Size:%s Size compare to 0x80000 Size: %s' % (test[4][0],diffArr4, self.checkSize(diffArr4))
        print 'Start Adresse %s: Size:%s Size compare to 0x80000 Size: %s' % (test[5][0],diffArr5, self.checkSize(diffArr5))
        print 'Start Adresse %s: Size:%s Size compare to 0x80000 Size: %s' % (test[6][0],diffArr6, self.checkSize(diffArr6))
        print 'Start Adresse %s: Size:%s Size compare to 0x80000 Size: %s' % (test[7][0],diffArr7, self.checkSize(diffArr7))
        print '================================'
        for i in range(0,parts):
            myListPoint.append(test[0][i])
        self.writeFile(self.pfad,myList)
        self.compareMap(self.findMap(),myListPoint,"0x80000",parts)
        print self.findMap()

    def checkSize(self, difference):
        sizeA = hex(self.sToH("0x80000"))
        #print sizeA
        #print difference
        if(difference<sizeA):
            result = "OK"
        else:
            result = "not OK"
        return result

    def compareMap(self,mapA,myList,sizeA,parts):
        result = ""
        for i in range(0,parts):
            difference = self.sToH(mapA) - self.sToH(myList[i].tostring()) 
            if(difference<sizeA):
                result = "OK"
            else:
                result = "not OK"
        print "mapA in Bereich. " + result      
        return result

    def sToH(self,hex_str):
        return int(hex_str, 16)

    def findA2l(self):
        concateFolderPathT1 =os.path.join(self.pfad,'*.a2l')
        folderT1=glob.glob(concateFolderPathT1)
        return folderT1[0]

    def findMap(self):
        concateFolderPathT1 =os.path.join(self.pfad,'*.map')
        folderT1=glob.glob(concateFolderPathT1)
        patern= re.compile("gVX1000 (b[a-f0-9]{5,8})")
        finded = "jhgj"
        for i , line in enumerate(open(folderT1[0])):
            for match in re.finditer(patern, line):
                filterString = match.group()
                finded = filterString.replace('gVX1000 ','')
        return "0x"+finded


objektvx = VXINI("C:\Users\user\Desktop\VX")
objektvx.generator(8)
```

How can i program this in python?

Comment: show us the code which you've tried.

Comment: How can i attach the code here beacause i am new here? The aim is to achieve 4 Lists that have list[len(list)-1]-list[0] should closer and smaller 0x80000.

Comment: @pavanskipo I have attach the code to this issue.Please can you help me?

Comment: can you give more details? Like what if there is no pair in the list whose difference is less than - 0x80000. Here is what I've tried so far https://repl.it/@pavanskipo/AustereMiserableInstructionset

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Then you should put all adress in the last array (list).Why your code is executed forwever.   print("current_index", current_index)

Comment: code is executed forever because "difference is less than" condition :). Didn't know on which condition to proceed further

Comment: The requirement is to divide this array in 4  small array and the element that can not fullfill the condition  0x80000 must be put in last array.  Tell me wich part you did not understand? If "difference is less than" condition than you need to create 4 array.

Comment: Please can you fix this script because i can not figure out why it is running forever what i need to change in it .   It print ony current_index 3

Comment: can you show me a sample output for this list [0x10004158, 0x10004166, 0x100041a0, 0x100041e8, 0x100041f4, 0xb00ac668,0xb00ac672, 0xb00ac676, 0xb00ac67e, 0xb00ac682, 0xb00ac686, 0xb00c077f], I'll change script accordingly

Comment: The output need to be array0[0x10004158, 0x10004166] **array1[ 0x100041a0, 0x100041e8, 0x100041f4, 0xb00ac668]  array2[0xb00ac672, 0xb00ac676, 0xb00ac67e]   array3[ 0xb00ac682, 0xb00ac686, 0xb00c077f]** with the above condition the element that does not fullfill the condition you can append at last array3. The conditon is that the difference is smaller than 0x80000. Thanks

Comment: in array1, the diference between the last and first is > 0x80000 right?

Comment: Yes you are right. Please please loop through myList[] and compare the diference between myList[i+1]-myList[i]  if it smaller than 0x80000 then append  to the first, second,third in the 4 array append only the element that do not fullfil this condition. Thanks

Comment: Hello @pavanskipo if you have question i will explain you.

Comment: give me a correct sample output for the list given in description

Comment: The output is to create few array : ARR1[0]-ARR1[len(ARR1)-1]<0x80000 ARR2[0]-ARR2[len(ARR2)-1]<0x80000 etc and the last array ARR6[0]-ARR6[len(ARR6)-1] > 0x80000

Comment: Please can you tell me if you have you understood you need to create 4 arrays and at leas array you can put all Exception. Thanks in Advance!